# Confusing ClassNotFoundException when instantiating JAXBContext with packageName and Classloader

Tags: java, jaxb, classloader

I'm trying to unmarshall an XML file into a generated class structure using JAXB in java. I'm running into a perplexing issue where the classloader I hand into `JAXBContext.newInstance(packageName, classLoader)` can apparently not find some of the necessary classes to instantiate the schema classes, but when I manually search the supplied classloader for the needed classes, they are there:

```
URLClassLoader cl = this.getJaxbClassloader();
try 
{
    cl.loadClass("org.postgresql.util.PGInterval");
    Log.error("Found class [" + name + "] in provided classloader");
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
{
    Log.error("Unable to find class [" + name + "]  in provided classloader");
}

JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.comp.gen", cl);
```

The `getJaxbClassloader()`  method just creates a new URLClassLoader, loading up some specific jars needed by the generated classes, and then setting the system classloader as the parent. The generated classes use some postgresql libraries that I put into the classloader, which is the resource I'm having the issue with. JAXB correctly finds the ObjectFactory class in the supplied package, it's just the instantiation of the generated classes themselves that seem be the problem.

The result of running this code is that the manual call of `cl.loadClass("org.postgresql.util.PGInterval");` works fine, it logs the the first statement saying that it found the class, no exceptions thrown. But when the `JAXBContext` is instantiated, it throws a CNFE on the exact same resource:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.util.PGInterval
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:600)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:772)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:745)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:726)
   ... 78 more
```

More Thorough stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.postgresql.util.PGInterval
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFieldsImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:740)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(RegistryInfoImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:357)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:327)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:184)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:144)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:346)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:443)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:406)
```

Anyone have an idea as to what's going wrong here? I was under the impression (and the JAXBContext docs support this) that it would use the supplied classloader to find an implementation classes needed to instantiate the classes, so given that the resource appears to be within the classloader I'm supplying, why is JAXB unable to find it?

EDIT:
Adding the relevant portion of the generated class that uses the PGInterval resource:

```
import org.postgresql.util.PGInterval;
...
... 
...
@XmlElement(name = "time_to_live", required=false)
protected PGInterval time_to_live;

public PGInterval gettime_to_live()
{
    return time_to_live;
}

public void settime_to_live(PGInterval time_to_live)
{
    this.time_to_live = time_to_live;
}
```

I guess it's worth noting that this this the only import in the generated class is that is not in java's standard library.

Comment: Interesting indeed. Could you share the class that has PGInterval attribute?

Comment: It's not really possible to post the code, the generated class is enormous (not by my design I might add... I'm working in someone else's codebase). But I can grab out the snippets of where PGInterval is used.

Comment: Lets check if we also can do this `cl.loadClass("org.postgresql.util.PGInterval").getDeclaredFields();` problem may be PGInterval itself. It seems it try to get fields of PGInterval.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but that call works fine. Getting the declared fields of the PGInterval class works.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not calling `JAXBContext.newInstance(TopLevelClass.class)`? If the top-level class reaches the `PGInterval` class statically it should be fine. You can also try `JAXBContext.newInstance("com.comp.gen", TopLevelClass.class.getClassLoader())`.

Comment: That's actually what I was doing originally when I hit the `ClassNotFoundException`, so I made my own classloader who's parent is the `TopLevelClass.class.getClassLoader()`.

Comment: I've recently made another discovery... When running the component as a standalone java executable, and specifying a classpath that contains all libraries and whatnot, it works fine. When running the code in tomcat from a restapi (which is what I really need to work) it runs into this error. So it seems obvious that some aspect of this problem is related to classloader-base stuff declared by the app-server/framework. But I'm still confused as to how the resource can be in the classloader I provide, but JAXB still fails to find it..?

Comment: Can you try to add this: Class.forName("org.postgresql.util.PGInterval") before the line which you create the JAXBContext?

Comment: Can you say name of the class which imports org.postgresql.util.PGInterval; in it (your last pasted portion of code)

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically generate classes and use them in the same run? Or you've generated the context before you run your code?

Comment: The name of the generated class is `ContentExportJAXB`. And yes, the classes are generated from jaxb templates earlier in the execution of the code (though in the same thread). I can try the `Class.forName` call.

Comment: The `Class.forName` call works fine, it can find the class

Comment: @user3062946 You should not post your answer inside the question. You can answer your own post and you should do this. Well I am not sure but may be if you get more than 2 upvotes you will get your bounty back as repo.

Comment: Not really worried about the bounty, but I'll answer it formally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I eventually figured this out. Deep within the code-base I was working in, a prior developer had created a custom dynamic classloader that used ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() as its parent. This custom classloader is actually used to load up the generated JAXB class from disk, and I was using that instance's classloader for the JAXB stuff. Once I saw that I instantly knew the problem.

The environment I was running in was a restapi on top of tomcat, so the system-classloader at my component level only contained the catalina jars required to bootstrap tomcat.

The prior developer only ever ran his code in a standalone JVM, where he provided a huge classpath. So although this was technically an environmental problem, the root cause was the usage of ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() as the parent of a new ClassLoader. Changing the parent to be something more logical, ie the containing class' classloader solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this FAQ](https://jaxb.java.net/faq/index.html#classloader), class loading issues can happen when JAXB is used in application containers and servers. The suggested solution is to use the current class loader when creating a `JAXBContext`:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.comp.gen", this.getClass().getClassLoader() );
```

**EDIT:**
By looking at the relevant code from the stack trace, the specified classloader is used to:

1. load the `ObjectFactory` class located in the specified package `com.comp.gen`.
2. load the classes specified in the `jaxb.index` file located also in the package.

cf. [`com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory#createContext(String contextPath, ClassLoader classLoader, Map<String,Object> properties)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/ContextFactory.java#ContextFactory.createContext%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.ClassLoader%2Cjava.util.Map%29):

```
// look for ObjectFactory and load it
final Class<?> o;
try {
    o = classLoader.loadClass(pkg+".ObjectFactory");
    classes.add(o);
    ...

// look for jaxb.index and load the list of classes
try {
    indexedClasses = loadIndexedClasses(pkg, classLoader);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
```

From then on it seems JAXB uses some sort of reflection to load all statically reachable classes from these already loaded classes. This is what is also mentioned in the [Javadocs of `JAXBContext#newInstance(String contextPath, ClassLoader classLoader)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)):

> Every package listed on the contextPath must meet one or both of the following conditions otherwise a JAXBException will be thrown:
>
> 1. it must contain ObjectFactory.class
> 2. it must contain jaxb.index
>
> **Format for jaxb.index**
>
> The file contains a newline-separated list of class names. Space and tab characters, as well as blank lines, are ignored. The comment character is '#' (0x23); on each line all characters following the first comment character are ignored. The file must be encoded in UTF-8. **Classes that are reachable, as defined in `newInstance(Class...)`, from the listed classes are also registered with JAXBContext**.

I assume (but this is the part I'm not sure of...) that all reachable classes would also be loaded using the classloader you provided. But obviously somewhere down the reference paths, the `org.postgresql.util.PGInterval` is **not** being loaded by that classloader. This may be the case if the class that references `org.postgresql.util.PGInterval` was itself not loaded by your custom classloader but by the parent (system) classloader. This means you may want to make sure your custom classloader is able to load all classes from the top-level class down to the `org.postgresql.util.PGInterval` class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had actually already tried this, but it's not really an option because the JAXB classes themselves are generated on the fly and not on the classpath of the default classloader. If I use the class' classloader, it simply cannot find the ObjectFactory within the desired package and fails. I need to be using the generated class' classloader in some regard, so that it can find the ObjectFactory.

Comment: @user3062946 Then in this case would using `GeneratedJAXBClass.class.getClassLoader()` work?

Comment: No, that's precisely the problem. That classloader does not containg the PGInterval resource that is needed. So I make a new classloader pointing to the URL of the PGInterval jar, and then set the `GeneratedJAXBClass.class.getClassLoader()` as its parent. But then JAXB just says that it cannot find PGInterval anyhow

Comment: Hey, thanks for the extra information. I'm not really sure to make of all of this. I've ensure that the classloader that initially loads `GeneratedJAXBClass.class` from disk also has `PGInterval` available, but still no changes. Like I said earlier, running the component in its own JVM solves the problem, but that's not really what I'm going for. I need to be able to run it in tomcat from a restful api. It really appears as though the classloader declarations by the app-server/framework are somehow messing with JAXB classloading...